# addOnSuccesListener execution order problem, firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a StorageReference element which stores a folder's reference from firebase and I loop through its elements in order to get every download link, but I don't understand why it's executed in this order. I've done something similar previously and it worked, but now for some reason, I don't understand why, it's not working as it should and why it jumps listeners this way.

```
private interface FirestoreCallback {
    void onCallback(List<Uri> uris);
}
```

```
public ArrayList<Uri> getAllDownloadURIs(final FirestoreCallback firestoreCallback) {
    StorageReference folderPath = ListVideoDates.storage.getReference((String) extra.getSerializable("folderPath"));
    System.out.println("FOLDER PATH: " + folderPath);

    final ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<>();

    folderPath.listAll()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
                    for (StorageReference file : listResult.getItems()) {
                        file.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                uris.add(uri);
                                System.out.println("Array inside onSucces2" + uris); // second
                                // here the array is printed as elements are 
                                //inserted, but this listener is the last 
                                //executed listener for some god damn reason

                            }
                        });
                    }
                   // firestoreCallback.onCallback(uris);
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
           // firestoreCallback.onCallback(uris);
            System.out.println("Array inside onSucces3" + uris); // first
        }
    });
```

Why the first listener executed is the second one and why then it jumps to the f "first" one? I've also tried to insert the callbacks in both locations ( commented above ) and it still doesn't work regardless of the listener order execution, it's still empty when I try to acces it with the method bellow.

```
public void setAllDownloadURIs() {
    getAllDownloadURIs(new FirestoreCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(List<Uri> uri) {
            uris = new ArrayList<>(uri);
            System.out.println("URIS inside onCallback: " + uris);
        }
    });
}
```

```
   FOLDER PATH: gs://***************************
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
I/System.out: URI inside setAllDownloadURIs: null
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
I/System.out: Array inside onSucces3[]
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/StorageUtil: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
W/NetworkRequest: no auth token for request
I/System.out: Array inside onSucces2
I/System.out: Array inside onSucces2
I/System.out: Array inside onSucces2
I/System.out: Array inside onSucces2
```

And here i get 4 array outputs since there are 4 elements in the folder and they're printed as the program is inserting them into the array.

Comment: The Firebase APIs are asynchronous and return immediately before the result it known. Your code continues to execute.  Some time later, the callbacks will be invoked with the results of the call.

Comment: I know they're asynchronous, that's why I use a callback so that I can access the values when they're completely  fetched, but for some reason it's not working properly.
And I would still like to understand why it jumps listeners that way, because if I chain multiple onCompleteListeners it doesn't follow the natural order as far as I can see.  ( at least in the way I think it now ).
What I think it should do is complete the first listener and it's children listeners and then continue to the last one. but it's backwards.

Comment: By the time your `return uris;` runs, none of your `uris.add(uri);` have happened yet. I'd recommend just removing that `return` as it makes it seem like you're stuck on something else than you actually are. There is indeed no guarantee that the completion listeners for `getDownloadUrl()` complete in order, so you'll have to track which download URL belong with what original call.

Comment: How do you suggest I  fix this? I've used a callback hoping it will fix this issue ( it worked before) , but it seems like it's not working in  this particular case.

Comment: From what I knew ```addOnSuccessListeners```are executed sequentially.